# Load items on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I have a "ul" with "li's" in it.
I need to find a way to load more items every time I reach the 10th item in the list. Every time I scroll to the 10th "li" I need to load more items.
Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: please put your codes

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting article about infinite scroll which load more items when you reach the end of the page: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

One of these examples uses the [jQuery Endless Scroll plugin](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll).

Hoping that might helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Endless Scroll plugin worked fine for me. Just needed to make some adjustments.